# MVC Controller returns HTML error page over HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, https, iis-express

I'm doing a POST in javascript to my MVC Controller. If something fails the server will catch the exception and return an error with the exception message. This works fine under HTTP. I enabled SSL on IIS Express, and all of a sudden the returned error contains the HTML of an error page, instead of the exception message.

What could be the cause of this?

This is in javascript:

```
var config = {
    url: "https://localhost:44301/update",
    type: "POST",
    data: data
};

$.ajax(config).fail(function (error) {
    // error.statusText contains exception.Message over HTTP
    // error.statusText contains "OK" over HTTPS (IIS Express)
});
```

And this is on the server:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("update")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    try
    {
        Update(id);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value or `url` that you use in `config`?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen I updated my question to reflect that :)

Comment: Has the port number changed, now you are using HTTPS?

Comment: what was the error code before turning on https? Was it a 500?

Comment: It's 100% hitting your action? It's not simply not hitting that?

Comment: Are you posting from a page delivered using the same HTTPS scheme?

Comment: @spender Yes. The page is https://localhost:44301

Comment: @KarlGjertsen The port is different now. But I request the resource from the same port. Before i requested it from http://localhost:8080 (and that same base url in javascript of course), now https://localhost:44301

Comment: What if you call the port from a web browser, passing in the expected id?

Comment: @Liam Nothing in the code has changed. Just which scheme I use

Comment: @Liam Can't test that right now since it is a POST, will have to modify some things then

Comment: Is there an error showing in the console window? Do you have Fiddler installed?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen No error in the console, I catch the error in javascript. If I run fiddler, I get the same as over HTTP. Which is a bit weird?

Comment: Does it hit the code in the controller?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen Yes, everything happens the exact same way server side

Comment: Probably should have asked earlier, but what does the error page say?

Comment: I know you keep saying nothing has changed server side, but how do you know it's hitting the server side code if you can't debug it? It sounds like the change of port has stopped the web site binding. so the url/port combination no longer maps to the correct place

Comment: @Liam Sorry if I mislead you. I can debug it. I'm running it on IIS Express via Visual Studio on my computer. But since I'm not at work anymore I can't try to change it from a POST method to a GET

Comment: @KarlGjertsen It's one of those default IIS error pages. Shows the error code, and my error message. And then some suggestions of what could be wrong (related to the error code I return, not my real problem)

Comment: @KarlGjertsen I think more and more that this is a bug with IIS Express 10. Can't really try it on a real IIS before getting a certificate

Comment: I've been looking at this and can;t see what the cause would be. Could you issue a self-signed cert?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen Yeah, I could do that. But even if it is a bug in IIS Express, I'd like to have the same result when debugging and running it locally, as I do on a real server. So I'm looking at finding another solution, for example divide my controllers into MVC controllers and WebApi controllers (for things that are requested by an ajax call), and hopefully that will work better